# DocuSign - Email Notification after Signing with attached document?

Tags: docusignapi

How do I change the following code to get email notifications and send signed copy via email?

```
    let customer = {
        email: app.application.email,
        // clientUserId: app.application.email, // added when they request embedded signing
        name: "name",
        roleName: 'customer',
        tabs: tabs,
        // recipientId: '1',
        // routingOrder: '1'
    }

    if (payload.customerSignMethod == 'Embed') {
        customer.clientUserId = app.application.email;
    }

    signers.push(

        docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject(customer)

    );

    envelope.templateRoles = signers;
    envelope.status = "sent";
```

Answer (score 0):

the commented line is the key:

```
 // clientUserId: 'cvbcvb@cvbcvb.com', // added when they request embedded signing
```

The way you had it, it should send email out to recipients, for remote signing.
If you put this line back in - it won't as it will be used for embedded signing.
If you have it commented, and still don't see the email, there's another issue.
Did you change the envelope status to "sent"? that should be done to actually send it.

Comment: So our clients are given a choice, they can in-person or remote. When they in-person, I add commented line back in. The issue is I want the signers to receive emails with completed pdf even if they choose in-person. How would I do that? I updated code to reflect that.

Comment: you can add them as a cc recipients at the end. Simple. Want me to write the code for this?

Comment: I did try that. Do I add it to the same signers array?

Comment: `signers.push(

   docusign.CarbonCopy.constructFromObject({
    email: app.coApplicant.email,
    name: "name",
    roleName: "cc"
   })
   
  );`

Is this what you meant?

Comment: yes, but you would have to use the routingOrder and make it more than everything else. That way, it will include the signatures that came first

Comment: you are using a template, right? you can change your template to that effect maybe.

Comment: routing order is like "1", "2" "3" etc. and it's the order in which the recipients get to sign/cc etc.

Comment: Do I push the email recipient object `templateRoles` or `carbonCopies`? I tried adding the routingOrder but emails are not recieved. Do I have to assign signing order on the Web UI as well or setting it here is enough?

Comment: I tried adding the CC as a signer but I haven't recieved any emails after all parties have signed.

`signers.push(

   docusign.CarbonCopy.constructFromObject({
    email: 'diffEmailFromCustomer@email.com',
    name: "same name",
    roleName: "cc",
    routingOrder: '4'
   })

  );`

Comment: Did you receive an email to diffEmailFromCustomer@email.com? does it not include the document or a link to the document? is the document empty?

Comment: Yeah, I recieved email at some point and it was empty and it let the user add new elements like textfield, etc. I am trying to add a `CertifiedDelivery` now but no email is delivering. I think since I just need a signed PDF, this is what I should use. According the API docs, email, name and roleName is necessary but no email is recieved after all parties signed. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: `signers.push(

   docusign.CertifiedDelivery.constructFromObject({
    email: 'customer@gmail.com',
    name: "name",
    roleName: "certifiedDeliveries"
   })

  );`

Comment: This should be very simple right. I have an embed signer but I want them to recieve a completed document when all parties sign. Why do I even have to create another Recipient like CertifiedDelivery.

Comment: You can go to the admin section of your account, then go to "Sending and Signing" "Email Preferences" on the left and make sure everything is checked. This is account-wide and not for a specific envelope or user.
"